# Shankaracharya is vaishnava according to Vedanta desikan?

Tags: vaishnavism, vishishtadvaita, reference-request

Many vaishnava tells Shankaracharya is vaishnava . I hear that vedanta Deshikan told shankaracharya is vaishnava. Any one can keep reference that vedanta desikan told shankaracharya is vaishnava?

Comment: you need a source other than "you heard"...

Comment: I need source( reference)